# How to conditionally set optional properties

Tags: typescript

Is there a shorthand way of conditionally setting an optional property?

Let's say I have this interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    someProp?: string;
    someOtherProp: string;
}
```

If I conditionally set the property I have to choose between some value and undefined. But if I don't set a value I don't want the property there at all. Currently the only way I can think of is this:

```
let object: MyInterface = {
    someOtherProp: "asd"
};
if (someCondition) object.someProp = "asdf";
```

I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

```
let object: MyInterface = {
    someProp: someCondition ? "asdf"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a way using property spread notation, but it involves (at least in theory) creating a temporary object that immediately becomes eligible for GC:

```
let object: MyInterface = {
    someOtherProp: "asd",
    ...(someCondition ? {someProp: "asdf"} : null)
};
```

Live Example:

```js
function create(someCondition) {
  return {
      someOtherProp: "asd",
      ...(someCondition ? {someProp: "asdf"} : null)
  };
}

console.log(create(true));
console.log(create(false));
```

That works because property spread silently ignores it if the value it's applied to is `undefined` or `null`. (This is different from *iterable* spread, which doesn't.)

Because it's syntax, in theory at least the JavaScript engine could optimize it if it were a hotspot. I have no idea whether they *do* (probably not yet, it's still relatively new), but...

Answer (score 3):

You can use object assign to conditionally merge - i find this option the most readable, personally.

```
let object = Object.assign({ someOtherProp: "asd" }, someCondition ? { someProp: "asdf" } : { });
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is *so* 2017... **;-)**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, it's not nearly as clever as a spread operator. At least my website is not so 2007 ;) Time for an update man!

Comment: Heh heh heh... I seem to have forgotten to vote. Fixed now.